# How to tag and label Google GCP load balancers?

Tags: google-compute-engine, google-cloud-platform

I am not seeing an option to tag google load balancers.  I can do it for compute instances. How can I tag LBs ?

Regards,

Muhammed Roshan

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's not supported yet.

List of currently resource types supported by Labels functionality as per [Compute Engine documentation](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/labeling-resources):

> - Virtual machine instances
> - Forwarding rules (Alpha)
> - Images
> - Persistent disks
> - Persistent disk snapshots
> - Static external IP addresses (Alpha)
> - VPN tunnels (Alpha)

Answer (score 1):

It is now also [possible](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/beta/compute/forwarding-rules/update#--update-labels) to set labels on load balancer forwarding rules (as well as on static external IP addresses and VPN tunnels)

E.g.

```
gcloud compute forwarding-rules update my-ilb --update-labels=key=value
```

Please check for more details in the gcloud [reference documentation](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/beta/compute/forwarding-rules/update#--update-labels).