# GCP - No tags for Global Load Balancer

Tags: google-cloud-platform

In my GCP account, I have created a custom VPC and 1 Subnet. I am running 3 instances in the subnet.

- all instances have only private IP. No public IP
- all instances running nginx. expose port 80

How to update the Firewall rules in a way that ONLY requests from global loadbalancer should be allowed. ? Interestingly GCP LoadBalancer does not seem to support ***tags***. So, I do not see an option to create firewall rule.

---

In AWS, LoadBalancers can be attached with SecurityGroups (say SG1). It enables us to update other Security Groups (say SG2) attached to the VMs to allow traffic from SG1.

Comment: Did you try giving the global load balancer's static IP in the firewall rule so that only traffic from that is allowed ?

Comment: I really do NOT like that idea. Then what is the purpose of having the tags. ?

Comment: I agree but I have not seen tags in HTTP(S) Load Balancer. Let me just check once more.

Comment: I updated the question. If you have used AWS, Security Groups do not work that way. I hate to rely on IP address

Comment: @RamPrakash Please let us know if this thread helps: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43998737/how-to-tag-and-label-google-gcp-load-balancers

Comment: Hey @JamesS is this possible only using gcloud cli command ? I have not noticed tags when I created a load balancer from Cloud console.

Comment: Create a VPC Firewall rule allowing traffic from the load balancers: `130.211.0.0/22` and `35.191.0.0/16`. However, this is not necessary. Since your instances do not have public IP addresses, what traffic are you trying to block? Only systems with routes into your VPC can connect. Examples: load balancers. VPC connectors, IAP, etc. You do not want to block those services.

Comment: @JohnHanley, Thanks. Looks like thats what we have to do.

Comment: @sidharth vijayakumar this feature is currently at its beta phase which is why its not available within the console at the moment. I should add that this only add labels to the LB's forwarding rules. In the mean time, a feature request has been raised for Network Tags in Load Balancers. Kindly follow this link: https://issuetracker.google.com/239552352 for updates and developments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per @John Hanley's advise, you may create a VPC Firewall rule allowing traffic from [Google's Front End](https://cloud.google.com/load-balancing/docs/https#:%7E:text=The%20IP%20address%20of%20the%20Google%20Front%20End%20(GFE)%20that%20connected%20to%20the%20backend.%20These%20IP%20addresses%20are%20in%20the%20130.211.0.0/22%20and%2035.191.0.0/16%20ranges) (35.191.0.0/16 and 130.211.0.0/22) that is connected to the backend. But this may not be necessary since your instances does not have public IPs. At the moment, it is only possible to [set labels on the Load Balancer's forwarding rule](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/beta/compute/forwarding-rules/update#--update-labels) but this is still in its beta phase.

Example:

`gcloud compute forwarding-rules update my-ilb --update-labels=key=value`

A feature request for Network Tags in Load Balancers has been raised. Please refer to this [link](https://issuetracker.google.com/239552352) and hit the `star icon` from the upper left and the `+1 button` on the upper right hand side of the page so you can follow the developments of this feature request. Please feel free to edit this post if you'd like to add more information.